# Do the "weak and ill suited for battle" weapons have any hidden stats or bonuses?

Tags: fire-emblem-awakening

In Fire Emblem Awakening, I have recently come accross 2 weapons, whose description says:
*Weak and ill suited for battle*.

Namely, the [Log](http://fireemblem.wikia.com/wiki/Log) and the [Slack Bow](http://fireemblem.wikia.com/wiki/Slack_Bow) and I believe there may be even more.

It wouldn't be the first time I've run accross weak weapons in the Fire Emblem games, but all "weak" weapons before those had some sort of benefit, such as extremely high accuracy or uses or could provoke status ailments (Poison).

I've been thinking about selling those weapons, but was unsure as to whether they may have some significance other than stats, or not.

This leads us to the question in my title:
**Do the "weak and ill suited for battle" weapons have any hidden stats or bonuses?**

Comment: Mostly, it's the hilarity factor.  Killing an enemy by smacking them with a Log or a Ladle is somewhat amusing.

Comment: They are joke weapons. For fun as fbueckert says. They also provide weapons for you to use against weaker "random" (map) encounters should you not want to waste your good weapons. (Though money is not really an object in the game so bronze/iron weapons work just as well).

Comment: By my count, this is the second time Taranto has linked to a SE site. I wonder how many SE users are also Best-of-the-Web readers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are simply novelty weapons. They are mostly for amusement and do not have any hidden stats.

Despite this, they do have the benefit of rank E weapon level requirement, making them great for raising weapon levels of recently class-changed units. For example, I currently have a streetpass team that I don't want to dismiss but am not yet strong enough to fight sitting on the only shop that sells bronze weapons, so I've been using ladles for my characters to get from axe rank E to D.

Novelty weapons include:

- Ladle (axe)
- Tree Branch (sword)
- Log (lance)
- Slack Bow (bow)
- Kneader (staff)

Comment: Lol, to think I didn't realize the `Kneader` belonged to the same category as the `Log` and the `Slack Bow`. Thanks for the answer, at least I know I can sell these without worry.

Comment: Maybe even add the Sweet Tinticure healing item to that list too.

Comment: I considered including Sweet Tincture, since it fits into that category of items, but I omitted it because it isn't a weapon.

Answer (score 4):

There are no bonuses for these weapons, but the fact that they do less damage than bronze weapons can make them useful in specific scenarios:

- You want to level a character's weapon rank, i.e. get more hits on an enemy before it dies.  This is especially useful in the case of the Kneader (a weaker heal), as I don't think you get rank for healing a fully healed unit.
- You want to give a specific unit the killing blow (the Donnel recruitment battle springs to mind): it can be useful to have a weaker weapon on a stronger unit in order to bring an enemy down to low enough health without killing them.
- You want to see someone get whopped with a ladle or poked with a log.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what's already been posted, they can also be upgraded to about the same stats as their iron counterparts without costing quite as much. It's cheaper to upgrade a tree branch to 5 attack power than to buy an iron sword.

Comment: Yeah, they are amazingly cheap to upgrade. Which can sometimes make them preferable to bronze weaponry when training weapon skills up from E-rank.

Comment: +1: It's been ages since I've played this, but I do forge them and it's actually an economical option.